# How to render a partial from another namespace in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial

In my Rails 3 project I have:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

scope :frontend do
  resources :users
end
```

There is a partial with filename "/views/admin/users/_form_fields.html.haml".

And I want to render it from "/views/frontend/users/_form.html.haml".

This code doesn't work:

```
render 'admin/users/form_fields', :f => f
```

Comment: Why not `render :partial => 'admin/users/form_fields', :locals => {:f => f}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass local variables you need this sintax:

```
render :partial => "/admin/users/form_fields", :locals => { :f => f }
```

Hope this helps. you can take a look to [Rails Guide: Using Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not in passing variables to the partial. The problem is how to set correct name for the partial from another namespace. "admin/users/form_fields" is incorrect one.

Comment: I think yout forgot one slash at the beginning: `"/admin/users/form_fields"` so it indicates that the route is absolute and not relative